# Can we retrieve asp.net project from azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am working on a asp.net test project. I were deploy the project to windows azure. After that I add some code and the project stop working, but the project on azure is still working. Is there any way that can make me retrieve the project from azure ?

In visual studio, I can connect to windows azure and displaying the projects that I deployed to it. I can see some of the files but not all. The important files for me which is the controller files doesn't appear. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure isn't source control. What you would have published to azure (I'm hoping) will not be the whole code but a 'published' version of it.

Short answer would be no

Answer (score 1):

When you publish a Web dev project to Azure **Visual Studio** compiles all the source code (.net) you have. Then the compilation results are binary files (.dll) and some other website assets like css,js and html files.

So there are no .Net source files from your project published into the website, because of that you can't get your source files again.

I strongly recommend you to check these links

- [Continuous deployment using GIT in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/)
- [Using Git
  in Visual Studio](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-746)
- [spanish demo - Repositorios Git privados y
  gratuitos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WVYnlnoubE)

Besides of that you can try to use any source code repository or ALM suite, As you're using azure you can also use **Visual Studio Online** to host your projects for free and also be able to publish directly to azure repositories.

more info [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can not get code from this method. use FTp tool, like **Core FTP**, **FileZilla** for that.

These are steps get ftp of your web application.

1. Go to **azure** (https://portal.azure.com).
2. Select **web app** from browser all option.
3. Select you app from list an then click on **settings** option.
4. Then click on **properties**, then enable you ftp and create password for that.
5. **FTP/Deployment User** , **FTP HOST Name** , **Password**

   ```
   Note: You will not get your code fils( .cs).
   ```